# How to make exec command in shell script run in different process?

Tags: bash, shell, fork, exec

I'm working with this GUI application, GTKWave, that has a startup script, `gtkwave`, which I've added to my system path. At the very end of said script, there is this line:

```
$EXEC "$bundle_contents/MacOS/$name-bin" $* $EXTRA_ARGS
```

where `$EXEC=exec`

My problem is that given how `exec` works, my terminal is "hijacked" by the GUI process, meaning I can't run any more commands until I close the window, which is not ideal.

I currently got around this by putting this function in my `.bash_profile`:

```
function run-gtkwave ( ) { nohup gtkwave $1 &>/dev/null & }
```

While this works, it makes it hard to pass arguments to `gtkwave`. Ideally, I could do a form right before that exec command, but I'm not sure how to do that in bash. I know that the `&` character should do that, but

```
$EXEC "$bundle_contents/MacOS/$name-bin" $* $EXTRA_ARGS &
```

doesn't cut it, and neither does

```
"$bundle_contents/MacOS/$name-bin" $* $EXTRA_ARGS &
```

or

```
("$bundle_contents/MacOS/$name-bin" $* $EXTRA_ARGS) &
```

How do I modify this line to run the application in its own process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `run-gtkwave` function pass arguments to `gtkwave` by changing the definition to:

```
function run-gtkwave { nohup gtkwave "$@" &>/dev/null & }
```

Since using `nohup` and output redirection stops the terminal being "hijacked", you might be able to fix the problem in `gtkwave` by doing the `nohup` redirection and the output redirection there.  (If standard input is a terminal, `nohup` redirects it from `/dev/null`.)  One possibility is:

```
"$bundle_contents/MacOS/$name-bin" $* $EXTRA_ARGS </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

(I've omitted the `$EXEC` because I can't see any point in using `exec` and `&` together.)